# Enabling buttons for web part of ArcGIS for SharePoint?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-maps-sharepoint

I am very sharepoint illiterate and have been trying to figure it out on my own.

I have ArcGIS for sharepoint installed and I can add it to a page I have checked out.

I cannot however use any buttons for the web part (they are all disabled) and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

I have searched relentlessly online for a solution, but could not find one.

If someone has an idea as to why this would be happening please let me know.

I also have the ESRI maps for sharepoint and can log into AGOL, but it seems I can't remain logged in, or get a permanent map to display on my page for clients.

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue, http://doc.arcgis.com/en/maps-for-sharepointhas some video to follow. if not contact esri support.

Comment: Well, when I go to the permissions area, it states I have full control of the site.  Is this what you are referring to?  Thanks for the link, that has basically been my goto for these questions, but I 'm running into some sort of roadblock.  Appreciate it!